# CesiumJS JSON - description image remove properties from infobox

Tags: javascript, json, cesiumjs

I have a JSON file with all the data that I need. I would like after this to able to pull data from the Database. After putting a description of my entity(image)it removes properties. Others entities without descriptions are showing them as they should. What am I missing?

JSON

```
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [80.2066734649931, 13.0187039189613]}, "color":{
        "rgba":[0,0,255,95]},
      "properties": {
        "Name": "Mika",
        "Age": 17,
        "Type": "Policeman",
        "description":"PICTURE:<div><img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-british-police-officer-140116003.jpg' height='300' width='300'></img><p></p>"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [ 120.2072495864164, 34.0191043036246]},
      "properties": {
          "Name": "Zika",
          "Age": "Worker"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": { "type": "Point","coordinates": [ 140.2067574402883, 84.0191983952581]},
      "properties": {
          "Name": "Pera",
          "Age": 23,
          "Type": "Student"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

App.js - loading data from JSON

```
let data = require('../data.json')
let dataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(data);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
```

I expect to have Name, Age and Type with the image in infobox.